# How do I use map to drop a variable from a list of data frames

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

How do I *drop* a variable with the same name in a list of dataframes using `map`? Sadly the variable appears in a different position in each data frame, so I can't drop it using its position. It has to be with its name.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-sample(letters, 100, replace=T)
var3<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
df2<-data.frame(var1, var3, var2)
list1<-list(df, df2)
library(purrr)
#This works, but it won't help me because var2 is in different positions. 
list1 %>%
map(., `[`, -2)
#This does not work. 
list1 %>% 
  map(., `[`, -c("var2"))
```

Comment: If the use of dplyr is ok: `map(., select, -var2)`.

Comment: ```lapply(list1, function(x) subset(x, select=-c(var2)))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```r
map(list1, ~ .x %>% select(-var2))
```

Or using NSE with a curly-curly expression

```r
name_excl <- "var2"
map(list1, ~ .x %>% select(-{{name_excl}}))
```